# Updating mysql database using jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using the following code to update my mysql database

```
String sql = "update stocks set price = ?, high = ?, change = ? where SYMBOL = ?";  
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 

for(int i=0;i<ing;i++)
 {   

    stmt.setString(1, price[i]); 
    stmt.setString(2, high[i]); 
    stmt.setDouble(3, changedvalue[i]); 
    stmt.setString(4, SYMBOL[i]);

    stmt.addBatch(); 
} 
stmt.executeBatch();
```

where changedvalue is a array of type double. If i remove change it executes properly. But with it it throws the following error.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'change = 0.1 where SYMBOL = ''' at line 1
What is the issue

Comment: Why do you have 4 parameters, but you're setting 8?

Comment: What's the type of `change` in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CHANGE is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. Try quoting it:

```
update stocks set price = ?, high = ?, `change` = ? where SYMBOL = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL has four parameters. Your code is setting eight. That can't possibly work.

Is this your actual code? If so, that's your problem, and the solution is to make your SQL and code match.

If not, show us your actual code.

Comment: Where do you see "setting eight parameters"?

Comment: @BartekJablonski: It was before the question was edited. See my comment on the question.

Comment: Either that or I started drinking early today.